# Draw high quality HTML to Graphics2D (analogous to drawString())

Tags: java, html, graphics2d

I know how to draw HTML to a Graphics2D object using Swing's limited built-in HTML support (see http://www.java.net/node/680674), but I need better rendering. Most importantly for this particular chemistry diagram drawing application, Swing's HTML support does not extend to nested sub/superscripts. Better CSS support would be nice too. I don't need image embedding or interactive features such as Javascript or hotlinks.

The HTML text is scaled and rotated and then drawn into a diagram that presumably contains additional text and graphics. The Graphics2D target may be the screen, a printer, or (via iText) a PDF file. I doubt that any solution involving conversion via a BufferedImage or the like can be adequately compact when producing PDF files of publication quality.

My (possibly incorrect) impression is that JavaFX 2.0 does not yet have a solution to this, though it might eventually. (If an earlier version can do this, that might be a solution.) Rewriting the entire application from Swing to JavaFX is not realistic.

This application is free and open source, so any tool it uses probably needs to be freely distributable also. Otherwise, I believe JWebEngine might have fit the bill.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a JavaFX [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) node - it has very good HTML tag and css support.  You can [rotate](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#rotateProperty) and [scale](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#scaleXProperty) the WebView node using JavaFX primitives.  [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) can be used within WebView to get high quality equation rendering (if just plain html and css alone doesn't do the job for you).  Using [JavaFX 2.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html), you can take a snapshot of the WebView node and render it to a JavaFX image.  You can convert that JavaFX image to an awt BufferedImage using JavaFX 2.2 SwingFXUtils and write it out to a file in many formats using [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html).

Here is an [example of rendering a piechart node to a png](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10394451).  Depending on the complexity of your html, sometimes an high quality image will compress well to (for example) a png file.  In the pichart sample, the 2000x2000 pixel piechart with text and colored gradients saved to a png file of 168kb.

Rewriting the entire application from Swing to JavaFX is not necessary as JavaFX includes the [JFXPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) for embedding JavaFX applications inside existing Swing applications.  The node snapshot step does not even require the node to be rendered to a screen (it can all be done through memory buffers) - though the JavaFX system would probably need to have been initiated and launched in a JavaFX application or a JFXPanel first.

All of the above may or may not end up giving you the result you want, but it seems a promising avenue to examine.

**Update**

I ran a couple of tests on this and though I can snapshot a WebView displayed on the screen as explained in this post, due to some limitation of JavaFX 2.2, I was unable to snapshot a WebView displayed as part of an offscreen scene.  This means that the information in this answer is accurate, but only applies to the portion of the HTML which can be displayed in the WebView on a screen; e.g. the technique will not currently work for large documents whose pixel size exceeds the screen pixel size.  For some sample code, see https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2456191.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching and scraping several pieces together I found that the only problem I had with the example in the **Update oracle forum link** above was that the size of the webview was fixed and that my **css used in the html** (not in JavaFX) needed.

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

to hide the last scrollbar.

So I come up with the following snapshot method (application with animation just as example of your application):

```
package application;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.effect.GaussianBlur;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class WebViewSnapshot extends Application {

    BorderPane rootPane;
    TranslateTransition animation;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50, 50, 50);
        rect.setFill(Color.CORAL);

        animation = createAnimation(rect);

        Button snapshotButton = new Button("Take snapshot");

        Pane pane = new Pane(rect);
        pane.setMinSize(600, 150);

        rootPane = new BorderPane(pane, null, null, snapshotButton, new Label("This is the main scene"));

        snapshotButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            // html file being shown in webview
            File htmlFile = new File ("generated/template.html");
            // the resulting snapshot png file
            File aboutFile = new File ("generated/about.png");
            generate(htmlFile, aboutFile, 1280, 720);
        });

        BorderPane.setAlignment(snapshotButton, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(snapshotButton, new Insets(5));
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private TranslateTransition createAnimation(Rectangle rect) {
        TranslateTransition animation = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), rect);
        animation.setByX(400);
        animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        animation.setAutoReverse(true);
        animation.play();
        return animation;
    }

    public void generate(File htmlFile, File outputFile, double width, double height) {
        animation.pause();
        // rootPane is the root of original scene in an FXML controller you get this when you assign it an id
        rootPane.setEffect(new GaussianBlur());
        Stage primaryStage = (Stage)rootPane.getScene().getWindow();
        // creating separate webview holding same html content as in original scene
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        // with the size I want the snapshot
        webView.setPrefSize(width, height);
        AnchorPane snapshotRoot = new AnchorPane(webView);
        webView.getEngine().load(htmlFile.toURI().toString());
        Stage popupStage = new Stage(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        popupStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        popupStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        // this popup doesn't really show anything size = 1x1, it just holds the snapshot-webview
        popupStage.setScene(new Scene(snapshotRoot, 1, 1));
        // pausing to make sure the webview/picture is completely rendered
        PauseTransition pt = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
        pt.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                WritableImage image = webView.snapshot(null, null);
                // writing a png to outputFile
                // writing a JPG like this will result in a pink JPG, see other posts
                // if somebody can scrape me simple code to convert it ARGB to RGB or something
                String format = "png";
                try {
                    ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), format, outputFile);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    rootPane.setEffect(null);
                    popupStage.hide();
                    animation.play();
                }
            }
        });
        // pausing, after pause onFinished event will take + write snapshot
        pt.play();
        // GO!
        popupStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```